What is the correct way of obtaining LWLocks in postgres?
As per the postgresql source code, there are two ways of obtaining LWLocks.
One way :
extern void RequestNamedLWLockTranche(const char *tranche_name, int num_lwlocks);
extern LWLockPadded *GetNamedLWLockTranche(const char *tranche_name);

Second way :
extern int  LWLockNewTrancheId(void);
extern void LWLockRegisterTranche(int tranche_id, const char *tranche_name);
extern void LWLockInitialize(LWLock *lock, int tranche_id);

Both methods can be utilized to acquire lwlocks in postgres. However, what is the distinction between the two methods and when to use the first method versus the second method is unclear.
The locks registered in both methods are ultimately stored in the MainLWLockArray as per the source code. [ pg version 11.4 ]
